# Energy-dependent neutron cross section data

Tags: neutrons, scattering-cross-section

Where I can find a table with energy dependent cross sections for neutrons?

Comment: neutron scattering against what? protons?  you can start with the particle data book http://pdg.lbl.gov/

Comment: This kind of data is most often accumulated in ENDFs, which are intended for computer consumptions, but can be read by a sufficiently persistent human. Many sources.

Answer (score 3):

Neutron-matter interaction cross-sections vary somewhat depending on the material in question, and depends greatly on energy. In addition, the type of neutron-matter interaction that statistically dominates depends on the energy, with elastic collision being the sole contributor to material cross-sections below energies of 4 MeV:
[image]

If you're talking about elastic scattering, another thing to note is that **protons are really good at thermalizing neutrons via elastic interaction**, a fact which owes primarily to the fact that neutrons and protons have similar masses. In contrast, scattering by larger atomic nuclei results in less effective thermalization:

[image]

A good approximate parametrization of the neutron-hydrogen elastic cross-section in units of barns is given by $$\sigma(E)=\frac{3 \pi }{(0.13 E+0.4223)^2+1.206 E},$$
as shown here:

[image]

The slides are taken from Wolf-Udo Schroeder's PHY466 notes at University of Rochester.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is the [National Nuclear Data Center's "Sigma" database](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/sigma/).  The web interface is much improved since the time this question was asked.